# qlYieldTSDiscount in QuantLib Python

Tags: python, quantlib

I have been using Quantlib Addin, now I am looking for the equivalent function for QuantLib in Python:

```
=qlYieldTSDiscount(EffectiveDate;DiscountCurve)
```

Or any workaround? I need to discount my NPV to today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be

```
discount_curve.discount(effective_date)
```

You'll find examples of various tasks in QuantLib-Python on [Goutham Balaraman's blog](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-python-tutorials-with-examples.html) or on the [QuantLib Python Cookbook](https://leanpub.com/quantlibpythoncookbook).  Having a look at those might ease your learning curve.